# plotting data from netcdf with cartopy isnt plotting data at 0 longitude

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, cartopy

im beggining my journey with gridded data, and ive been trying to plot some temperature data from a netcdf file with cartopy. I followed some examples and i cant understand why my plots have a white line in the middle. (i already checked the data and the matrices are full with numbers, no NaNs)

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatterimport glob


data = xr.open_dataset('aux1.nc')
lat = data.lat
lon = data.lon
time = data.time
Temp = data.air


#Calculo la temperatura media anual
Tanual = Temp.resample(time="y").mean()
#Promedio de todos los meses
Tprom = Temp.mean(dim="time").values


#Grafico
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
ct = ax.contourf(lon,lat,Tprom,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap="bwr")
ax.gridlines()
cb = plt.colorbar(ct,orientation="vertical",extendrect='True')
cb.set_label("Temperatura [°C]")
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-180,181,60), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-90,91,30), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPHz4.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! The problem is that for most gridded climate data the longitude coordinate looks something like:

```
array([1.25, 3.75, 6.25, ..., 351.25, 353.75, 356.25, 358.75])
```

So there's no explicit `longitude=0` point, and this often gives you a thin white line in the plot. I see this problem in published papers (even 'Nature') sometimes too!

There are many ways to get around this, but the easiest way is to use the `cartopy` package, which has a utility called `add_cyclic_point` that basically interpolates the data either side of the `longitude=0` point. (Ref: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/cartopy/util/util.html)

The only downside of this method is that when using `xarray` it means you have to extract the data manually and then you lose the metadata, so here's a function I wrote to keep this nice and easy to use, while maintaining metadata.

```py
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point
import xarray as xr 

def xr_add_cyclic_point(da):
    """
    Inputs
    da: xr.DataArray with dimensions (time,lat,lon)
    """

    # Use add_cyclic_point to interpolate input data
    lon_idx = da.dims.index('lon')
    wrap_data, wrap_lon = add_cyclic_point(da.values, coord=da.lon, axis=lon_idx)

    # Generate output DataArray with new data but same structure as input
    outp_da = xr.DataArray(data=wrap_data, 
                           coords = {'time': da.time, 'lat': da.lat, 'lon': wrap_lon}, 
                           dims=da.dims, 
                           attrs=da.attrs)
    
    return outp_da
```

**Example**

So, for example, if my initial DataArray looks like:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'tas' (time: 60, lat: 90, lon: 144)>
[777600 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -89.49 -87.98 -85.96 -83.93 ... 85.96 87.98 89.49
  * lon      (lon) float64 1.25 3.75 6.25 8.75 11.25 ... 351.3 353.8 356.2 358.8
  * time     (time) object 1901-01-16 12:00:00 ... 1905-12-16 12:00:00
Attributes:
    long_name:         Near-Surface Air Temperature
    units:             K
    valid_range:       [100. 400.]
    cell_methods:      time: mean
    standard_name:     air_temperature
    original_units:    deg_k
    original_name:     t_ref
    cell_measures:     area: areacella
    associated_files:  baseURL: http://cmip-pcmdi.llnl.gov/CMIP5/dataLocation...
```

And when I plotting the time-mean, gives this:

```
tas.mean(dim='time').plot.contourf()
```

[image]

Now, I can use my function to generate a new, interpolated DataArray like this:

```
wrapped_tas = xr_add_cyclic_point(tas)
```

```
wrapped_tas

<xarray.DataArray (time: 60, lat: 90, lon: 145)>
array([[[251.19466, 251.19469, 251.19472, ..., 251.19226, 251.19073,
         251.19466], ...
        [250.39403, 250.39468, 250.39961, ..., 250.39429, 250.39409,
         250.39403]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) object 1901-01-16 12:00:00 ... 1905-12-16 12:00:00
  * lat      (lat) float64 -89.49 -87.98 -85.96 -83.93 ... 85.96 87.98 89.49
  * lon      (lon) float64 1.25 3.75 6.25 8.75 11.25 ... 353.8 356.2 358.8 361.2
Attributes:
    long_name:         Near-Surface Air Temperature
    units:             K
    valid_range:       [100. 400.]
    cell_methods:      time: mean
    standard_name:     air_temperature
    original_units:    deg_k
    original_name:     t_ref
    cell_measures:     area: areacella
    associated_files:  baseURL: http://cmip-pcmdi.llnl.gov/CMIP5/dataLocation...
```

As you can see, the longitude coordinate has been extended by one point, to go from 144->145 length, this means it now 'wraps around' the `longitude=0` point.

This new DataArray, when plotted, gives a plot without the white line :)

```
wrapped_tas.mean(dim='time').plot.contour()
```

[image]

Hope that helps!! :)