# interpolation periodic boundaries with xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I would like to interpolate many `xarray` datasets containig global climate data to one common grid. `xarray` actually has an [`interp()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html#) method which works fine, but as far as I can tell does not take any periodic boundries into account, although this is necessary when interpolating on a sphere. Instead, datapoints which are outside of the old grid are extrapolated or filled with NaNs. The interpolation is based on the scipy package, and I think other interpolation methods from scipy also do not support periodic boundaries.

I am considering using [xesmf](https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but was wondering if there is an easier solution for this just using xarray?

I would prefer linear interpolation but am flexible in this regard.

Comment: xesmf is the easy solution for xarray as far as I know. It's works very well based on my experience. especially if you have no nan values (i.e. if you interpolate both ocean and land).

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out? I have the same issue and I'm considering using [`xgcm`](https://xgcm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#), but haven't been able to figure everything out

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, if you are willing to wrap your data in the longitudinal direction. With some assumptions (`DataArray` has coords 'lon' and 'lat', 'lon' spans almost 0-360 and doesn't quite go to the boundaries), and borrowing some ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60913814/54557), this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data = np.arange(360 * 180).reshape(360, 180)

lon = np.linspace(0.5, 359.5, 360)
lat = np.linspace(-89.5, 89.5, 180)

da = xr.DataArray(
    coords=dict(
        lon=lon,
        lat=lat,
    ),
    data=data,
)

# These will both print 'nan' as lon is outside 0.5-359.5
print(da.interp(lon=0.3, lat=32).values)
print(da.interp(lon=359.7, lat=32).values)

def xr_add_cyclic_points(da):
    """
    Add cyclic points at start and end of `lon` dimension of data array.
    
    Inputs
    da: xr.DataArray including dimensions (lat,lon)
    """
    # Borrows heavily from cartopy.util.add_cyclic point, but adds at start and end.

    lon_idx = da.dims.index('lon')
    
    start_slice = [slice(None)] * da.ndim
    end_slice = [slice(None)] * da.ndim
    start_slice[lon_idx] = slice(0, 1)
    end_slice[lon_idx] = slice(-1, None)
    
    wrap_data = np.concatenate([da.values[tuple(end_slice)], da.values, da.values[tuple(start_slice)]], axis=lon_idx)
    wrap_lon = np.concatenate([da.lon.values[-1:] - 360, da.lon.values, da.lon.values[0:1] + 360])

    # Generate output DataArray with new data but same structure as input
    outp_da = xr.DataArray(data=wrap_data, 
                           coords=dict(lat=da.lat, lon=wrap_lon), 
                           dims=da.dims, 
                           attrs=da.attrs)
    
    return outp_da

da_wrapped = xr_add_cyclic_points(da)

# These will print interpolated values.
print(da_wrapped.interp(lon=0.3, lat=32).values)
print(da_wrapped.interp(lon=359.7, lat=32).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is to use the `.interp` method from xarray and pass `kwargs={'fill_value': 'extrapolate'}` as an argument. This way, the white range with NaNs will also be interpolated in the process.

Here the simple code to solve this problem.

```
# Load packages
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# Load data
ds = xr.open_dataset('your_data.nc')

# Interpolate data
# Create a reference grid (1x1)
lat_new = np.arange(-90, 91, 1)
lon_new = np.arange(-180., 181., 1)

ds_interp = ds.interp(lat=lat_new, lon=lon_new, method='linear', kwargs={'fill_value': 'extrapolate'})
```

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `xr_add_cyclic_points` function in [@markmuetz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73557332/14595507) can also be achieved using xarray's `pad` method:

```py
ds_lon_wrapped = (
    ds.pad(lon=1, mode="wrap")
    .assign_coords(lon=ds.lon.pad(lon=1, mode="reflect", reflect_type="odd"))
    .assign(lon_bnds=ds.lon_bnds.pad(lon=1, mode="reflect", reflect_type="odd"))
)
```